# Twitter Bootstrap not working in IE 8 or IE 9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap

I am very confused as to why the Twitter Bootstrap is not working in Internet Explorer 8 or 9. It is working just fine on all the other browsers including Safari, Firefox and Chrome. I have been debugging the code through a later version of Internet Explorer and I have found this error: SCRIPT5009: '$' is undefined. Here is the code that it points to:

```
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
$(this).tab('show');
})
```

It said it's the first line, first character. It allows the user to click the drop down but it is jumbled up and unreadable. I am using the standard Bootstrap javascript files. Any help would be appreciated and please let me know if I should provide any more code.

Here is the source code for the page:

```
<head>
<script>
jQuery('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
jQuery(this).tab('show');
})
</script>
<script src="_internal/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" type="text/javascript" ></script> 
<script src="_internal/js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="_internal/js/bootstrap-transition.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="_internal/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script> 
<script src="_internal/js/bootstrap-tab.js" type="text/javascript" ></script> 

<link href="_internal/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="_internal/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<div class="accordion-group">
<div class="accordion-heading">
<a class="accordion-toggle" data-parent="#accordion2" data-toggle="collapse" 
href = "#collapseFive">
    Title goes here
  </a>
</div>
<div class="accordion-body collapse" id="collapseFive" style="height: 0px;">
<div class="accordion-inner">
<table cellpadding="15" summary="table">
<tbody cellpadding="4">
<tr class="table-row">
<td width="250">Text</td>
<td width="250">Text</td>
<td width="200">Text</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="250"><a href="link" title="title">title</a></td>
<td width="250">text/td>
<td width="200">text</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="250"><a href="link">title</a></td>
<td width="250">text</td>
<td width="200">text</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Try using `jQuery` instead of `$`

Comment: As I answered, you try to use jQuery _before_ it is actually included. That is the answer, Move your function below or `<script src="_internal/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>` above.

Answer (score 1):

use `jQuery()` instead of `$()`. I don't know why jQuery isn't loading the `$()` selector, but I had an issue like this the other day and changing all the `$()` selectors to `jQuery()` fixed it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried doing what you have suggested but it did not make a difference. I posted much of the source code to the post to try to see what the problem is. Thanks

Comment: Maybe try using an IFFE to properly set $. $ may be held by another library like the Prototype Javascript library when you use it. An IFFE will help if that is true.

Answer (score 1):

You probably run / declare this function ***before*** you include jquery. When you are not wrapping the function into a `document.ready()`, neither `$` nor `jQuery` is defined at the execution point.

People often forget that, when they copy-paste the bootstrap homepage html or the examples, and then starts writing jquery-code as they are used to - as jquery is included in `<head>` and not before `</body>`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I posted much of the source code to this post. I see what you are saying but it looks like I included the jQuery in the <head>. If I did not, please let me know. Thanks

Comment: @Chase552, Yeah, but you declare your function - that will be executed immediately - _before_ the jQuery-include. So the page does not know `$` or `jQuery` at the execution-moment.

Answer (score 1):

This should make things work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $.noConflict(); //Case sensitive
</script>
```